# Want to display the current date/time

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Hi I'm using php and sql through odbc to write a program and i hav got abit stuck in a part where i want to display the current date/time in the format date('Y-m-d H:i:s) but it only displays the gmt time. I want to add 8hours to it.Can any of you b able to help me.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set). You can do something like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
print 'Current datetime is: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You could use that to set the timezone to whatever timezone you need time to be at, and then use `date` normally. Alternatively, you can do this, using [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
print 'Current datetime is: ' date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+8 hours'));
```

Comment: yes but this only displays the GMT time the time i want is 8hours faster

Comment: You can set the timezone to whatever timezone you want and get the right time.

Comment: Or you can use the 2nd method I put to simply add 8 hours to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to display a timestamp in a user's local time, you can use JavaScript:

```
function showtime(t)
{
    if (t == 0)
    {
        document.write("never");
        return;
    }

    var currentTime = new Date(t);
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    document.write();
    if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10){
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ");
    if(hours > 11){
    document.write("PM");
    } else {
    document.write("AM");
    }
}
```

Then if you need to display a time, just make a call to it in the HTML and splice in the value from PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">showtime(<?=$time."000"?>)</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would steer clear of the timezone method.

If i understood correctly, you want to add time, thus change it. An example could be, A task has been created NOW, and must be complete in 8 hours. The timezone method would only change the *display* of the date and time. Only change the timezone setting if you know your visitor's timezone, and datetime's must be shown relative to them.

Now: 1234418228 is 2009/02/12 00:57:08 in Montreal or 2009/02/11 09:57:08 in San Francisco. It's the exact same moment.

Appending to the first answer, date() and strtotime() are your friends.

strtotime( "+8 hours", $now )
$now being a timestamp of when it's supposed to relate to. So if your start time isn't time(), you can still use that. eg

```
strtotime( "+8 hours", strtotime( "2009/03/01 00:00:00" ); (8AM on 2009/03/01)
```

However, when dealing with intervals counted in weeks, or less, i prefer doing it 'mathematically'

```
$StartTime = strtotime( "2009/03/01 13:00:00" );
$EndTime = $StartTime + ( 8 * 60 * 60 );
date( "Y/m/d H:i:s", $EndTime ) ==> "2009/03/01 21:00:00"
```

3600 seconds in an hour, 86400 in a day.

You can't use this method for months, quarters or years because the number of seconds they last varies from one to the next.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use time for a certain timezone, then using date_default_timezone_set() is preferred. anyway you can provide the date() function another parmater: int timestamp. an integer representing the timestamp you would like date() to return the information about.
so if you would like to show date('Y-m-d H:i:s') for now you can use this:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() ); // time() returns current timestamp.
// if you omit the second parameter of date(), it will use current timestamp
// by default.
$_8hoursLater = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+60*60*8 );
$_8hoursBefore = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-60*60*8 );
```